# angular mat-date-range-picker month view only

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-datepicker

Is it possible to select a range only in month view?

```js
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Enter a date range</mat-label>
  <mat-date-range-input
    [formGroup]="range"
    [rangePicker]="picker"
    [dateFilter]='dateFilter'>
    <input matStartDate placeholder="Start date" formControlName="start">
    <input matEndDate placeholder="End date" formControlName="end">
  </mat-date-range-input>
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-date-range-picker (monthSelected)='monthSelectedHandler($event, picker)' startView='year' (opened)='clearSelectedDates()' #picker></mat-date-range-picker>
</mat-form-field>
```

e.g.
[image]